# How to get direct link to file uploaded via form?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps Script to upload a file to a folder in my Google Drive. Is it possible, in apps script, to get a direct link to a file that I had just uploaded? Currently, I am only able to get a link to the folder where I am saving all my files.

Code I am using to upload files:

```js
function processForm(theForm) {
  try{
    var fileBlob1 = theForm.resumeFile;
    var fileBlob2 = theForm.piFile;

    var fldrSssn = DriveApp.getFolderById('My Folder ID');
    fldrSssn.createFile(fileBlob1);
    fldrSssn.createFile(fileBlob2);
    return fldrSssn.getUrl();

  }catch(e) {
      Logger.log(e);
  }//End catch
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to keep the File object that is returned by [`Folder.createFile()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createFile(BlobSource)), then use that to retrieve the [file url](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createFile(BlobSource)).

```js
function processForm(theForm) {
  try{
    var fileBlob1 = theForm.resumeFile;
    var fileBlob2 = theForm.piFile;

    var fldrSssn = DriveApp.getFolderById('My Folder ID');
    var file1 = fldrSssn.createFile(fileBlob1);
    var file2 = fldrSssn.createFile(fileBlob2);

    // Return all URLs in a single object
    return { 
      folderURL: fldrSssn.getUrl(),
      file1URL:  file1.getUrl(),
      file2URL:  file2.getUrl()
    };

  }catch(e) {
      Logger.log(e);
  }//End catch
}
```